# Trying To AutoUpdate My Datagrid by Refreshing the Dataset in My WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I hope someone can help me as I am a real newbie.  I have a WPF Application that is bound to an SQL database on my webServer.  Information updating the database is done from an automated trading platform.  This application is being designed just to monitor the changes in real time.  Binding the data from the webserver to the datagrid was no problem.  However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the datagrid update in realtime.  The closest I could do was add a refresh button which does successfully update the application everytime I click it.  However, I would like it to autoupdate on its own whenever the database has automated changes.  Can someone please show me how I can modify my code to make this work? I have placed my code below. Thanks!

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using C1.WPF.DataGrid;
using StylingWPFGrid.ForexDataSetTableAdapters;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System;

namespace StylingWPFGrid
{ 
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class WPFGrid : Window
{

    private ForexDataSet _infoDataSet = null;
    public ForexDataSet infoDataSet
    {
        get
        {
            if (_infoDataSet == null)
            {
                _infoDataSet = new ForexDataSet();
                infoTableAdapter info = new infoTableAdapter();
                info.Fill(_infoDataSet.info);
            }

            return _infoDataSet;

        }
    }

    private ForexDataSet _tradesDataSet = null;
    public ForexDataSet tradesDataSet
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tradesDataSet == null)
            {
                _tradesDataSet = new ForexDataSet();
                tradesTableAdapter trades = new tradesTableAdapter();
                trades.Fill(_tradesDataSet.trades);
            }
            return _tradesDataSet;
        }
    }
    public WPFGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); this.AccountsDataGrid.ItemsSource = infoDataSet.info;
        InitializeComponent(); this.TradesDataGrid.ItemsSource = tradesDataSet.trades;

    }

    private void QuitBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void RefreshBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        infoTableAdapter info = new infoTableAdapter();
        info.Fill(_infoDataSet.info);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you don't have anything setting your properties. So nothing is being updated. That is only part of the problem. The other issue is that you will need to impliment the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public partial class WPFGrid : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
         {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
         }
      }
}
```

Then for your properties you should do:

```
public ForexDataSet tradesDataSet
{
   get{//add your code here}
   set
   {
      _tradesDataSet = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("tradesDataSet");
   }
}
```

Also ensure you are using two way binding if you expect your control to update your database.

Another note: You shouldn't require `InitializeComponent();` in your constructor twice! It should be the first line in your constructor and the other two should come after.

The other suggestions to set this up on a timer are good ideas also. I would attempt to do that also, unless you have something setting your datasets. [backgroundworker](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) is a good example.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback,  I have fixed the Initialize Component and set up binding now for TwoWay. Having problems with exactly where to place the INotifyPropertyChange within my code but I will keep at it.  Thanks again.

Comment: I updated the code to show you where the interface should be placed.

Comment: Billy,I attempted to insert everything as you have shown and only had one red underline error when i did that and that was under the last "e" in the line:                                  PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e)); However, when i ran the application I had no error or warnings and the application came up and did not refresh.

Comment: Good point... That is a copy and paste error on my part! The "e" should be changed to "propertyName", I updated the post. With the code above you will still need something calling the set on the property. Stephan B and tsells suggestions can be used to help with this issue.

Comment: I have posted the modified code that I hope you can look at here.  Also, I noticed that a line was automatically inserted at the bottom of the code when I ran the application:                public string e { get; set; }
(http://www.pippintothetop.com/WPF%20Refresh.txt)

Comment: I don't see the updated code. However what happened with the e is that it made a property out of it. That is not what you want. The e was a cut and paste error on my part. It should have been the input variable that was passed into the method.

Comment: Billy, I have added the propertyName in place of the e.  I also removed that one line that popped up before at the end of my code.  Please let me know if everything I did looks correct overall before I continue.  Then I will look how i can implement a DispatcherTimer() in order to see the data update.  Hope I am the right track :)

Comment: Please check the link I sent as I have updated everything I hope to your satisfaction so far.  I tested the link and had no problems opening up the page. Thanks!

Comment: I looked over it and you have made the updates correctly however you still don't have have anything calling or setting the properties in your form. So the only thing you are missing now (that I see) is that something has to populate the properties. This can be accomplished thru the web service sending out Change Events that you register for (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/WebServiceWithEvents.aspx) or you can just setup a timer on a background thread and pull the data at intervals. Either way you have to have something setting your properties so your bound data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Info from the Database that it has been updated I believe, so you can just use a Timer to "click" the Button every Second. If the DB cannot handle this try to write a small query that scans for the last update and only fetch the data if this is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your data in this application is not bound to the database.  It is bound to the DataSet you created.

```
private ForexDataSet _infoDataSet = null;
public ForexDataSet infoDataSet
```

Since this is a client application using a CLR call back function from the server would not be the best solution.  I think in this case setting up an "auto refresh" feature would be sufficient.  You could use a timer as suggested previously.  I would however do this on a back ground thread (Backgroundworker) so you don't affect the UI while polling for changes.